# Create Automation using Fuel SDK API in node.js

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, marketing-cloud-connect

I need to create an **automation** in **Marketing Cloud** using **fuelSDK-node**. I cannot find any documentation regarding the same but I got documentation for **.NET** code

Can anyone please help me with the same?

Comment: Why would you want/need to do this?

Comment: Our application has a requirement to "create automation on user's org" through fuelSDK

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @lan Hoar, I used the SOAP APIs